# Wordpress selecting wrong DB

Tags: database, wordpress, database-connection

I have a Wordpress site that uses two databases -- one section queries one database ("database_A"), and then Wordpress makes its connection to its own database ("database_B").

Everything it working well until I go to call this function:

```
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

The Wordpress suddenly selects the wrong database ("database_A") when it was just using ("database_B").

How do I (a) prevent it from selecting ("database_A") or (b) make a call to have it select ("database_B")?

Comment: I think you might need to post some more code around the problem area. The most obvious explanation is that `$wpdb` is changing, but without more code it's going to be impossible to say why.

Comment: I admit this is bit of a gray area, but I think this would be better suited on serverfault or superuser

Comment: Nope, this is definitely a programming question and belongs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wpdb class in WP ha a select() method. You should just be able to call it directly.

```
$wpdb->select('database_B');
```

You could also instantiate a second object that uses database_b:

```
$wpdb_b = new wpdb($db_b_user, $db_b_pwd, 'database_B', $db_b_host);
```

Comment: Thanks Jage! That worked well in reconnecting to the Wordpress Database!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new $wpdb-var, like this:

```
<?php
$wpdb2 = new wpdb($user, $dbpassword, $db2, $dbhost);
?>
```

Now you can easily select items from the other database:

```
<?php
$pageposts = $wpdb2->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
?>
```

I hope it helps you :]

(edit: Are you sure it suddenly changes the database? I mean, is it using `database A` before it is using `database B`, that's almost impossible...)